# vector linear combinations in 3d space

Tags: vectors

[image]

My text has an example as follows:

Three vectors, **V** **U** and **W**, in three dimension space.

They ask to locate two other vectors:

a) 1/3V + 1/3W + 1/3U

b) 1/2W + 1/2U

the answers:

a) falls in the middle of the triangle whose vertices are W, U, and V.

b) falls midway on the line between W and U

I stare at it and think, "yeah, ok, looks right" but honestly I cannot prove to myself why, and I also cannot think of other examples to look at to reinforce that I really understand this.

I guess the answer for 'a' is something like, "well, the vectors W and U and V are all points on a plane defined by the linear combinations of cW+dU+eV"   Therefore the example c=d=e=1/3 is also going to be on that same plane.    But I'm missing how that sticks it in the middle of that U-W-V triangle.

And similarly for the part-b question, it sounds right, but I don't have a relationship that I can exploit to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can work the other way around. Take part (b), for example.

Given the vectors $W$ and $U$, points on the line joining $w$ with $u$ have position vectors $p = W + k(U-W)$, where k is a scalar.

This is because if you complete the vector addition triangle, $W+\overline{wu} = U$.

When k=0, $p=W$

When k=1, $p=W+U-W = U$.

So as you vary k from 0 to 1 you get points on the line $wu$ (you're doing a linear  interpolation, really).

The midpoint is halfway along the vector from u to w (k=1/2), which shows you that the midpoint i.e. $p = W + (1/2) (U-W)$ = (1/2)W + (1/2) U, which is what part (b) asserts.

Comment: The solution approach solves using  "position function = vector equation"  (W+k(U-W)) = 1/2W + 1/2U.    I'm trying to use same approach for the second example, but I am not sure how to specify the position function.  W + k(U-W) + ???  if I put the third component in terms of d(V-K(U-W), I just wind up with two free konstants that i cannot solve.  If I use the same konstant k to define the third component, k(V-k(U-W)), I wind up with k^2 terms which makes no sense.

Comment: I do not find this convoluted answer helping anyone who is just beginning to learn L.A. This is a challenge question from Strang's book. What really saved me was the excellent video from [khan acad](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/geometry-home/triangle-properties/medians-centroids/v/triangle-medians-and-centroids). The reason why $1/3u+1/3v+1/3w$ is the center of the triangle boils down to a fundamental property of triangles.